# Serious overhead in Python cProfile?

Tags: python, performance, time, profile, cprofile

Hi expert Pythonists out there, I am starting to use cProfile so as to have a more detailed timing information on my program. However, it's quite disturbing to me that there's a significant overhead. Any idea why cProfile reported 7 seconds while time module only reported 2 seconds in the code below?

```
# a simple function

def f(a, b):
 c = a+b

# a simple loop
def loop():
 for i in xrange(10000000):
  f(1,2)

# timing using time module
# 2 seconds on my computer
from time import time
x = time()
loop()
y = time()
print 'Time taken %.3f s.' % (y-x)

# timing using cProfile
# 7 seconds on my computer
import cProfile
cProfile.runctx('loop()', globals(), locals())
```

Answer (score 6):

Because it's doing a lot more work?  `time` just times the whole operation, while `cProfile` runs it under instrumentation so it can get a detailed breakdown.  Obviously, profiling is not meant to be used in production, so a 2.5x overhead seems like a small price to pay.

Comment: Also the function is so trivial that the profiler will seem to take up a lot of the total run time in relative terms.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

If I increase the number of iterations in loop() from 10 millions to 100 millions, the timing scales linearly! time module took 20s and cProfile took 70s. I DO NOT MIND if cProfile takes longer to run, but the reported time (i.e. actual time spent in the code) should exclude the overhead. Is there a way to  calibrate cProfile (as I am only interested in the actual time spent in the code)?

Comment: @xqx: Not that I'm aware of. Profiling gives you an idea of the _relative_ performance of different parts of your program, but it's not suitable for production performance reporting.

Comment: Thanks Owen. I am not sure how much we can rely on the relative performance numbers as given by python's profilers because the overhead cost isn't guaranteed to be uniformly distributed. Is it possible that the overhead in some functions to be large (say 10x) while others insignificant and hence distorting the results. I am not sure how the profiling packages are implemented, so I don't know what factors do add up to the overhead. The number of sub-function calls is definitely one factor, as explained by unutbu's reply below.

Comment: As Einstein's realized,  there are no truly static experiments.

Answer (score 1):

The function `f` returns very quickly. When you use cProfile, the time being attributed to one call to `f` is not accurate because the time is so small that it is comparable to the error in measuring time. The clock used to measure differences in time may only be accurate to 0.001s. So the error in each measurement may be orders of magnitude greater that the time you are trying to measure. Do this 1e7 times and you've got bogus results. (See http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#limitations for more discussion of this.)

Notice that if you change the code to use

```
def f(a, b):
 for i in xrange(int(1e4)):    
     c = a+b

# a simple loop
def loop():
 for i in xrange(int(1e3)):
  f(1,2)
```

you get

```
Time taken 0.732 s.
         1003 function calls in 0.725 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.725    0.725 <string>:1(<module>)
     1000    0.723    0.001    0.723    0.001 test.py:4(f)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.725    0.725 test.py:9(loop)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

You are doing the same number of loops, but each call to `f` takes longer. This cuts down on the error per measurement. (The time attributed to each call to `f` contains an error which is now not as large the total time measured.)

Comment: Hi unutbu. In your example, the time taken with and without using the profiler are quite close i.e. 0.732s and 0.725s. Besides the possible introduced error as you mentioned, I think in my example the function f is called many more times (1e7 as opposed to 1e3 in your example), hence having more profiling cost.